# Iota Whitepaper: What is "k" in Section 3?

Tags: tangle, white-paper

The [IOTA Whitepaper](https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf) in Section 3 does not seem to define k. Is k the number of verifications required by a transaction as noted earlier in the Whitepaper or something else? If it's the former I do not understand.  Can someone people please help me understand?

Section 3

> ## Stability of the system, and cutsets
>
> Let *L(t)* be the total number of
> tips in the system at time *t*. One expects that thestochastic process
> *L(t)* remains stable. More precisely, one expects the process to be
> *positive recurrent*, see Sections 4.4 and 6.5 of [11] for formal
> definitions. In particular, positive recurrence implies that the limit
> of *P[L(t) =**k**]* as *t → ∞* should exist and be positive for all k ≥1.
> Intuitively, we expect that *L(t)* should fluctuate around a constant
> value, and not escape to infinity. If *L(t)* were to escape to infinity,
> many unapproved transactions would be left behind.

Section 1

> This is the simplest approach. One may also study similar systems where transactions must approve ***k*** other transactions for a general *k ≥
> 2*, or have an entirely different set of rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *k* from the footnote of section 1 is the required number of transactions to be referenced by new transactions (as is noted by you in your question).

The *k* from section 3 is just an index/placeholder in the context of number of tips overall (not the number of tips to be referenced), and one could have used any letter here.

For example, *The limit of P[L(t) = m] as t → ∞ should exist and be positive for all m ≥1* conveys the same meaning.

Comment: What's P[ ]  signify?

Comment: @ClarenceLiu P[A] denotes the probability of an event A happening.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, *k* is a "variable" used to make the English sentence easier to understand, the variable is both defined and used within the sentence, but nowhere else. The meaning of these two *k* is therefore different.

So the second example could be rewritten as

> One may also study similar systems where each transaction must approve a constant number of other transactions, where this number mentioned in the first half of the sentence needs to be larger than or equal to 2…